# HTML/JavaScript: accessing the wrapping document of an embedded svg

Tags: javascript

I have a html-page with an embedded (with object-tag) svg-graphic. 
In svg I have some javascript-action (e.g. click on a text-element), whichs working fine.

How can I access the elements of my root-document (the wrapping html of the embedded svg)??
document.getElementById is working on the svg-document but not on the upper one.

By example I will click in the svg and set the text of an div that is in the outer html.

any ideas? thanks for help!

br, chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.top.document
```

should do it